# How to sort on multiple field inside a list with easy admin?

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, easyadmin

With easy admin you have the possibility to sort on one field for a list.
[Symfony - Easy Admin v2: Sorting Entity Listings](https://symfony.com/doc/2/bundles/EasyAdminBundle/book/list-search-show-configuration.html#sorting-entity-listings)
But is there any way to sort on more than one field for my list ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do it overriding `createListQueryBuilder` or `createSearchQueryBuilder` as mentioned [here](https://symfony.com/doc/2/bundles/EasyAdminBundle/book/complex-dynamic-backends.html).

Example:

```
protected function createListQueryBuilder($entityClass, $sortDirection, $sortField = null, $dqlFilter = null)
{
    /* @var EntityManager */
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManagerForClass($this->entity['class']);

    /* @var QueryBuilder */
    $queryBuilder = $em->createQueryBuilder()
        ->select('entity')
        ->from($this->entity['class'], 'entity')
        ;

    if (!empty($dqlFilter)) {
        $queryBuilder->andWhere($dqlFilter);
    }

    $queryBuilder->addOrderBy('entity.status', 'ASC');
    $queryBuilder->addOrderBy('entity.createdAt', 'DESC');

    return $queryBuilder;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer. The only change I made was to enclose the `$queryBuilder->addOrderBy()` statements in an `if ...` to avoid exceptions on entities without the given entity properties. The use case was sorting on lastname, firstname, which only occur in the User entity.